# PHP: Include with template system

Tags: php, include

I have files listed at /home/Discussions/include/  want to contain within my guide library at /home/Library/index.php. How do I go about doing this?

This is the current code I have:

```
<?php
define('path_var', dirname(__FILE__).'/../Discsusions');
require path_var.'/include/common.php';
include path_var.'/include/header.php';
?>
```

I've tried many different variations and such and I just can't seem to fix this issue.

**Update: My directory structure is thus:**

```
/home/index.php (splash page)
/home/Discussions/index.php (talk page)
/home/Library/index.php (hopeful new guides page)
```

Comment: Can you explain your actual directory structure?

Comment: `Discsusions` is misspelled in your define.

Comment: One thing that would help is to do an `echo` on `path_var.'/include/common.php'` to see what file you are actually trying to include.

Comment: This is what I get from echo: /home/Library/../Discussions/include/common.php

Answer (score 1):

`__FILE__` is the absolute path to the current script. so given your script path of

```
/home/Library/index.php
```

then

```
dirname(__FILE__) -> /home/Library
```

and

```
dirname(__FILE__) .'/../Discsusions' -> /home/Library/../Discussions
```

which is equivalent to

```
/home/Discussions
```

So, `path_var = /home/Discussions`. So your include calls are going to be:

```
require path_var.'/include/common.php';
require '/home/Discussions/include/common.php';
```

So your code SHOULD be working. Are you sure that your script has the rights to read things from both directories?